# Pages restricted to certain IPs, safe?

Tags: network, web-application, authentication, ip-spoofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what scenarios is relying on source IP address as a security control acceptable/unacceptable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4533/in-what-scenarios-is-relying-on-source-ip-address-as-a-security-control-acceptabl)

If a website has a page which only renders for certain IPs, is there anything an attacker could realistically do to access such a page?

Comment: You mean... other than spoof their IP, or pwn a system that's in the whitelisted IP range(s)?

Comment: You might also be interested in http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4533

Comment: @Iszi How would one "spoof" an IP in such a way so as to still get a response from the server?